# Relationship between two differently sampled Fourier coefficients

Tags: signal-processing, fourier

Assume a periodic signal \$s(t)\$ with fundamental period \$T_0\$. If one were to use the period \$kT_0\$ to find the Fourier series coefficients, how would they be related to the standard Fourier coefficients obtained using \$T_0\$?

Comment: \$T_0\$ = `\$T_0\$`

Comment: Since the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) for finding the coefficient contains a division by the assumed period (in this case, \$k T_0\$), the coefficient would likely remain the same (but its index shifted by \$k\$ units). Please [edit] into the question, the formula for finding the coefficient.

Comment: You asked this on [dsp.ee, too](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/73931/17189).